# Python alphanumeric

Tags: python, for-loop, text, alphanumeric

**Problem:**

I have to go through text file that has lines of strings and determine about each line if it is alphanumeric or not. If the line is alphanumeric print for example "5345m345ö34l is alphanumeric"

Example of the text file:

```
5345m345ö34l 

no2no123non4 

%#""SGMSGSER
```

My code is as follows:

```
file = open('file.txt','r')
data = file.readlines()

for i in data:
    i.strip()
    if (i.isalnum()):
        print (i, 'is alphanumeric')
    else:
        print (i, 'not alphanumeric')
    file.close()
```

We can see that the first and second line is alphanumeric but the program doesn't work?

Comment: `data = file.read()`

Comment: Try: `i = i.strip()` (as strings are _immutable_ and their methods don't operate on their internal data, but rather return other strings). And also, fix your indentation.

Comment: How doesn't it work? Are you receiving errors? Are you getting an unexpected output?

Comment: @PrestonM: most likely, no line is alphanumeric because of the trailing _eoln_.

Comment: I've made some major changes to my answer which should solve your problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this and see if this working -

```
file = open('file.txt','r')
data = file.readlines()

for i in data:
    stripped_line = i.strip()
    if (stripped_line.isalnum()):
       print (stripped_line, 'is alphanumeric')
    else:
       print (stripped_line, 'not alphanumeric')
file.close()
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I was looking for. Each line had to be stripped because it contained a space in the end which is not part of alphanumeric. What I did wrong was not storing the stripped variable into a variable. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

## EDIT

From your original post you want to treat latin characters (i.e. those with accents) as valid alphanumeric input. In order to do this you should load the original file in unicode and when testing for alphanumeric qualities you should convert the accented letters to normal alphabetic. This will do that:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import unicodedata
import codecs

file = codecs.open('file.txt','rb', encoding="utf-8")
data = file.readlines()
for i in data:
    i = i.strip()
    converted_data = ''.join((c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFD', i) if unicodedata.category(c) != 'Mn'))
    if (converted_data.isalnum()):
        print (i, 'is alphanumeric')
    else:
        print (i, 'not alphanumeric')
file.close()
```

Comment: If indentation were the problem it wouldn't even run.

Comment: It's probably not the problem but we can only go from the original post and if the poster copies my code directly into their terminal then they should note all differences.

Comment: We don't need the `readlines` here. A file is iterable, so `for i in file:` would be enough and it could handle files that won't fit in the computers memory.

Comment: That is true @Matthias I have changed it above.