# Python3 - reading a CSV file and making changes

Tags: python-3.x

Write a function that reads a CSV file (textFile.csv), removes all whitespace and stores each word in a list

So far I have:

```
 fileobj = open(‘textFile.csv’, ‘r’)
```

Unsure how to remove the whitespaces and store each word in a list

Comment: leading or trailing or spaces at random locations

Comment: use strip function to remove all whitespaces etc and see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44394647/python-alphanumeric/44394750#44394750 , please upvote it if you found it useful